# What is mac process 'wirelessproxd'

Tags: macos, process, osx-yosemite

A process called `wirelessproxd` is running on `port 80` in my mac. What does this process mean? [This](http://cirrusj.github.io/Yosemite-Stop-Launch/) also does not have any information on it. Any help is appreciated.

OS - OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

I thought it has got something to do with File/Remote sharing options which I had turned on, similar to `wirelessradiomanagerd` process, but turning them off didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: afaik, it's part of Continuity/Handoff. Been in the OS since Yosemite.